# Como eu listo um usuário buscado no banco de dados com uma JTable?

Tags: java

**Classe DAO**

```
package DAO;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class conectaBD {

    public static Connection conectabd() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
             Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/crud","postgres","tmk9405");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Conectado com sucesso!");
            return con;
        }

        catch (SQLException error) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);
            return null;
        }   
    }
}
```

**Form LOGIN**

```
package visual;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.sql.*;
import DAO.conectaBD;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class frmLogin extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frmLogin frame = new frmLogin();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    private JTextField txtUsuario;
    private JPasswordField txtSenha;
    private JLabel lblLogin;
    private JLabel lblSistemaDesenvolvidoPela;

    public frmLogin() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Alessandro\\Downloads\\icons8-senha-50.png"));
        setTitle("Login de usu\u00E1rio");


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 640, 299);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblUsurio = new JLabel("Usu\u00E1rio:");
        lblUsurio.setBounds(139, 70, 85, 20);
        lblUsurio.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblUsurio.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        contentPane.add(lblUsurio);

        txtUsuario = new JTextField();
        txtUsuario.setBounds(224, 73, 179, 20);
        txtUsuario.setColumns(10);
        contentPane.add(txtUsuario);

        JLabel lblSenha = new JLabel("senha:");
        lblSenha.setBounds(139, 106, 85, 20);
        lblSenha.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblSenha.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        contentPane.add(lblSenha);

        JButton btnEntrar = new JButton("ENTRAR");
        btnEntrar.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Alessandro\\Downloads\\icones\\Icones\\accept.png"));
        btnEntrar.setBounds(262, 166, 104, 23);
        btnEntrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Logar();
            }
        });

        txtSenha = new JPasswordField();
        txtSenha.setBounds(224, 107, 179, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtSenha);
        contentPane.add(btnEntrar);

        lblLogin = new JLabel("LOGIN");
        lblLogin.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
        lblLogin.setBounds(262, 11, 67, 21);
        contentPane.add(lblLogin);

        lblSistemaDesenvolvidoPela = new JLabel("Sistema desenvolvido por Alesssandro Jacques.)");
        lblSistemaDesenvolvidoPela.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        lblSistemaDesenvolvidoPela.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        lblSistemaDesenvolvidoPela.setBounds(233, 256, 391, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblSistemaDesenvolvidoPela);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // centralizando formulario
        con = conectaBD.conectabd();

        setResizable(false); //Bloquando a opção maximizar a tela de login
    }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void Logar() {
            String sql = "Select * from login where usuario = ? and senha = ?";
            try {
                pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, txtUsuario.getText());
                pst.setString(2, txtSenha.getText());

                rs = pst.executeQuery();

                if(rs.next()) {
                    frmPrincipal frm = new frmPrincipal();
                    frm.setVisible(true);
                    dispose();
                }else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Usuario e senha inválidos.");
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException error) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);
            }
        }

    }
```

**Form PRINCIPAL**

```
package visual;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class frmPrincipal extends JFrame {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtBusca;
    private JButton btnLimpar;
    private JButton btnSair;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    frmPrincipal frame = new frmPrincipal();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Connection conectabd=null;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public frmPrincipal() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1124, 744);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblPesquisar = new JLabel("Pesquisar:");
        lblPesquisar.setBounds(50, 52, 85, 33);
        lblPesquisar.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        contentPane.add(lblPesquisar);

        txtBusca = new JTextField();
        txtBusca.setBounds(140, 62, 260, 23);
        txtBusca.setColumns(10);
        contentPane.add(txtBusca);
        //pesquisarUsuarios();

        JButton btnBuscar = new JButton("Buscar");
        btnBuscar.setBounds(410, 60, 108, 23);
        btnBuscar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
        btnBuscar.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Alessandro\\Downloads\\icons8-pesquisar-filled-25.png"));
        contentPane.add(btnBuscar);

        btnLimpar = new JButton("Limpar ");
        btnLimpar.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Alessandro\\Downloads\\icons8-limpar-pesquisa-25.png"));
        btnLimpar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txtBusca.setText(null);

            }
        });
        btnLimpar.setBounds(523, 107, 115, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnLimpar);

        btnSair = new JButton("SAIR");
        btnSair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnSair.setBounds(410, 107, 108, 23);
        btnSair.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        btnSair.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Alessandro\\Downloads\\icons8-fechar-janela-25.png"));
        contentPane.add(btnSair);

        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // utiliza para maximizar o formulário
        //setResizable(false); //Bloquando a opção maximizar

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); //tirando a opção fechar o JFRAME

    }
}
```

Comment: Seja mais específico quanto ao seu problema. Explique para quem ler sua pergunta quais os problemas que está enfrentando. Junte informações como stacktrace, mensagens e logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caram sua pergunta ta meio bagunçada e seu código não ta ajudando muito, mas valos lá... Pelo que entendi do titutlo da pertunta é listar ou preencher uma jtable com usuarios de um banco de dados..

Bom pra isso voce vai ter que ter seu metodo findAll(ou sei la que nome voce usou para isso), mas que retorne todos seus usuarios em uma List.. como por exemplo:

```
public List<Usuario> findAll(){
   //...retorna uma lista contendo todos os usuarios no banco de dados..
}
```

no seu form implemente uma procedimento que preencha toda sua jtable:

```
public void atualizarTable(){
   DefaultTableModel tb = (DefaultTableModel) JTable1.getModel();
   tb.setRowCount(0);
   List<Usuario> usuarios = new UsuarioDAO().findAll(); //aqui ele buscaria todos os usuarios vindos do metodo DAO..
   for (Usuario u:usuarios){
      Object[] dado = {u.getnome,u.getcpf,u.getSeiLaOq};
      tb.addRow(dado);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deixa eu tentar reformular, no campo de pesquisa quero pesquisar um usuário (que vai estar cadastrado no banco de dados) e listar ele com os dados do mesmo. Assim com os demais, por isso queria uma JTable ou Array List, mas não sei como fazer. Mostrar um usuário de cada vez.

Comment: Tente colocar um if antes do tb.addRow(dado), por exemplo: if (usuario.getNome().contains(campoPesquisa.getText())).. isso adicionaria somente os usuários que contém o nome que você digitou em determinado text... para isso inclua um evento KeyPress que chama o atualizarTabela(), e passa para ele o texto atual da pesquisa... xD